# Where does this point to in module scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

What object does `this` reference in module scope (i'm referring to node.js modules)?

```
console.log(this);
console.log(this === module); //false
```

It isn't referencing to `module` object so where is it pointing to?

Comment: Do you refer to node.js modules or ES6 modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, it's equal to `module.exports`

```
console.log(this === module.exports); // => true
```

Personally, I think this is dumb. But it is what it is.

I have no idea why we have *3* references to the same exact thing. `this`, `exports`, and `module.exports` all reference the same object.

My best guess is it's some backwards compatibility. I could easily be wrong about that tho.

Comment: Do you know what is the reasoning for this?

Comment: It should equal `process`

Comment: @self, I disagree, if anything I'd like `this === global` the way `this === window` in the root scope of a browser. Not that I think I'd just it; just for the sake of some sort of consistency. Or heck, have it be `undefined` because it makes no goddamned sense.

Comment: Process is the global object though

Comment: That's not true. `console.log(process === gloabal); // => false`